# How to speed up string splitting and write to excel? (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, split, openpyxl

I have a list of strings with 8192 elements like this `my_list = ['10000', '00100', ..., '11101']`. I want to split each element into a single character and write to a row in an excel file. That is, the first element `'10000'` will be `'1', '0', '0', '0', and '0'` where each value will be written a column of the excel file (along with two other values). For that, I tried typecasting a single string to list and used openpyxl to write to the excel file.

```
# run_experiment.py

import openpyxl as xl
import os
import time

result_source = "server_1"
n_instance = 50

'''
Some experiments will generate the `my_list` and one `time_stamp`. 
`my_list` is actually a 2D list of strings i.e., list of list of strings
of dimension [n_instance] x [8192].

This `run_experiment.py` will be run a number of times 
at different times of the day. For each run, therefore, the `time_stamp`
will be different. 
'''

filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "memory_{}.xlsx".format(result_source))

if not os.path.exists(filepath):
    wb = xl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    first_row = ['Time Stamp', 'Result Source', 'Result-1',
                 'Result-2', 'Result-3', 'Result-4', 'Result-5']
    ws.append(first_row)
    wb.save(filename='memory_{}'.format(result_source))


wb = xl.load_workbook(filename = 'memory_{}.xlsx'.format(result_source))
ws = wb.active
for i in range(n_instance):
    for j in range(8192): 
        row = list(my_list[i][j])
        row.insert(0, result_source)
        row.insert(0, time_stamp)
        ws.append(row)

wb.save(filename='memory_{}.xlsx'.format(result_source))
```

However, this approach is very slow. As I have to write data from multiple `result_source`, it becomes even slower. Is there a faster to achieve this?

Comment: I this all you are doing, or are there parts of your program that require the `openpyxl` library? You could do this quite easily with `pandas`, but I'm not sure if other parts of your code might require functionality from `openpyxl` that is not avaailable in `pandas`.

Comment: `openpyxl` is only used here. No other block needs `openpyxl`.

Comment: The code is incomplete, but as you are editing an existing file options are somewhat limited. You could get some improvement by creating the list in a single step: `[timestamp, result_source] + list(my_list[i])`. (And iterate directly over the list).

Comment: Using Pandas here won't really help because you have to convert from openpyxl to pandas and back.

Comment: @CharlieClark I have edited the code to make it more complete.

Comment: Are `result_source` and `time_stamp` constants? What do existing workbooks contain?

Comment: `result_source` is constant, but `time_stamp` is not. The file will be run several times. Each run will have a single but different `time_stamp`. The very first run of the python file will create one `.xlsx`. It will contain 7 columns. The first column is the `result_source` that is basically the name/identifier on which the experiments are run. The second column is the `time_stamp` telling me at what time the experiment was run. The remaining columns will contain the data each of them is either 1 or 0. 
From the next run, it will just add new experimental data to the existing `.xlsx` file.

Comment: I edited the code. It now resembles the full thing that I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, or if this is the most efficient way to do it, but I'm fairly new to Python myself.

Splitting the numbers is easy with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

mylist = ['00100', '10000', '11100']
data = pd.DataFrame(mylist) 
data[0] = data[0].astype('str') 

data = data.loc[:, 0].str.split("",expand=True)
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to be faster than `mylist = [list(i) for i in mylist]`, in fact considerably slow.